# Fixing the seed for parallel simulation runs with different number of cores

Tags: r, random, foreach

I'd like to parallelize a simulation study to speed it up and I'd also like to account for reproducibility. In particular, I'd like to obtain the same result as if I used `set.seed` at the beginning of a sequential simulation run.
Here is an example how I try to set it up (I purposefully use `.inorder=T` here):

```
library(doSNOW)
library(rlecuyer)

nr.cores = 4
nr.simulations = 10 
sample.size = 100000

seed = 12345

cl = makeCluster(nr.cores)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
clusterExport(cl=cl, list=c('sample.size'), envir=environment())
clusterSetupRNGstream(cl,rep(seed,6))

result = foreach(i=1:nr.simulations, .combine = 'c', .inorder=T)%dopar%{
  tmp = rnorm(sample.size)
  tmp[sample.size]
}

stopCluster(cl)

print(paste0('nr.cores = ',nr.cores,'; seed = ',seed,'; time =',Sys.time()))
print(result)
```

There are two questions that I have after running this example several times:

1. The number of cores impacts the resulting sequence, e.g., for `nr.cores=1` and `4` only the first values coincide, and for `nr.cores=4` and `8` the first four values coincide.
   Is there a way to have it independent of the `nr.cores`? Conceptually, I’d imagine I could create an RNG stream of size `nr.simulations * sample.size`, split it to `nr.simulations` pieces and distribute them to the nodes always in the same order. Even simpler, I could fix `nr.simulations` values of (different) seeds and again pass them in a fixed order to the nodes. This could be done having some kind of node mapping which could be used by the nodes to read its appropriate seed value from a table. Is there a way to do it?
2. When I run the script several times it happens (not always but from time to time) that the resulting sequence is reordered even though I do not change any of the parameters (I just source the file again and again). It just looks like a bug to me as either `.inorder` or `clusterSetupRNGstream` fail. Or am I missing something?

   ```
   [1] "nr.cores = 4; seed = 12345; time =2017-09-08 19:00:24"
   [1]  1.327091137 -1.800244293 -1.163391460  0.005980001  0.957521136  1.641354433 -1.219033091
   [8] -0.238129356 -0.225193384  1.457018576

   [1] "nr.cores = 4; seed = 12345; time =2017-09-08 19:00:28"
   [1]  1.327091137 -1.800244293 -1.163391460  0.005980001 -0.238129356  0.957521136  1.641354433
   [8] -1.219033091  0.870269174 -0.225193384
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that the ``.inorder`` parameter is just saying that you need the results in order, not that they will be computed in order. So maybe, sometimes, cluster 1 is computing the iteration 5, and sometimes 6? I'll further investigate when I have more time.

Comment: I recommend the doRNG package ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st Q**: The following seemed to work for me

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(5)
registerDoParallel(cl)
seedlist <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500)
clusterExport(cl, 'seedlist')
foreach(I=1:5) %dopar% {set.seed(seedlist[I]); runif(1)}

[[1]]
[1] 0.3077661

[[2]]
[1] 0.5337724

[[3]]
[1] 0.9152467

[[4]]
[1] 0.1499731

[[5]]
[1] 0.8336


set.seed(100)
runif(1)
[1] 0.3077661
```

**2nd Q**: Seems like a bug but maybe someone else has a better clue

Answer (score 1):

So, to prove my point that the `.inorder` parameter is just saying that you need the results in order, not that they will be computed in order, you can do

```
cl = makeCluster(nr.cores)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
replicate(10, {
  foreach(ic = 1:8, .combine = 'c', .inorder = TRUE) %dopar% {
    Sys.sleep(runif(1))
    Sys.getpid()
  } 
})
stopCluster(cl)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] 9252 9252 9252 9252 9252 9252 9252 9252 9252  9252
[2,] 9259 9259 9259 9259 9259 9259 9259 9259 9259  9259
[3,] 9266 9266 9266 9266 9266 9266 9266 9266 9266  9266
[4,] 9273 9273 9273 9273 9273 9273 9273 9273 9273  9273
[5,] 9273 9252 9259 9266 9273 9266 9252 9252 9266  9252
[6,] 9266 9266 9273 9273 9273 9259 9266 9259 9273  9266
[7,] 9266 9259 9252 9259 9259 9273 9273 9252 9259  9266
[8,] 9252 9252 9259 9266 9252 9252 9266 9252 9273  9259
```

Hum, not sure it really prove my point. It just shows that the clusters are computing in order at the beginning and then the first which finishes continues to compute.

---

As suggested by @Roland, you could use the [package **doRNG**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRNG/vignettes/doRNG.pdf) to do what you want. Let us verify:

```
library(doRNG)
cl = makeCluster(nr.cores)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
replicate(14, {
  set.seed(12345)
  sample.size = 100000
  foreach(ic = 1:8, .combine = 'c', .inorder = TRUE) %dorng% {
    Sys.sleep(runif(1))
    tmp = rnorm(sample.size)
    tmp[sample.size]
  } 
})
stopCluster(cl)

            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        [,7]
[1,]  0.42281264  0.42281264  0.42281264  0.42281264  0.42281264  0.42281264  0.42281264
[2,] -1.67678339 -1.67678339 -1.67678339 -1.67678339 -1.67678339 -1.67678339 -1.67678339
[3,] -0.49011636 -0.49011636 -0.49011636 -0.49011636 -0.49011636 -0.49011636 -0.49011636
[4,] -0.87165416 -0.87165416 -0.87165416 -0.87165416 -0.87165416 -0.87165416 -0.87165416
[5,] -1.02636022 -1.02636022 -1.02636022 -1.02636022 -1.02636022 -1.02636022 -1.02636022
[6,]  0.56549835  0.56549835  0.56549835  0.56549835  0.56549835  0.56549835  0.56549835
[7,]  0.03998101  0.03998101  0.03998101  0.03998101  0.03998101  0.03998101  0.03998101
[8,] -0.38754750 -0.38754750 -0.38754750 -0.38754750 -0.38754750 -0.38754750 -0.38754750
            [,8]        [,9]       [,10]       [,11]       [,12]       [,13]       [,14]
[1,]  0.42281264  0.42281264  0.42281264  0.42281264  0.42281264  0.42281264  0.42281264
[2,] -1.67678339 -1.67678339 -1.67678339 -1.67678339 -1.67678339 -1.67678339 -1.67678339
[3,] -0.49011636 -0.49011636 -0.49011636 -0.49011636 -0.49011636 -0.49011636 -0.49011636
[4,] -0.87165416 -0.87165416 -0.87165416 -0.87165416 -0.87165416 -0.87165416 -0.87165416
[5,] -1.02636022 -1.02636022 -1.02636022 -1.02636022 -1.02636022 -1.02636022 -1.02636022
[6,]  0.56549835  0.56549835  0.56549835  0.56549835  0.56549835  0.56549835  0.56549835
[7,]  0.03998101  0.03998101  0.03998101  0.03998101  0.03998101  0.03998101  0.03998101
[8,] -0.38754750 -0.38754750 -0.38754750 -0.38754750 -0.38754750 -0.38754750 -0.38754750
```