# Different result in parallel algorithm vs sequential algorithm in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, svm, feature-selection, random-seed

I paralleled Msvm-RFE algorithm with Rmpi
http://www.colbyimaging.com/wiki/statistics/msvm-rfe
that is used for feature selection. in result, I will have 6 features but one of this features in parallel algorithm vs sequential algorithm is different. this algorithm use seed() function and K-fold cv. when I changed the initial values in seed function, the results became the same but only when I have the small number of features.
my question is What is the cause of this difference? and can I ignore this difference or not?

Comment: Sometimes, you use a sequence of seeds when using parallelism. So, every run will give the same results, but not the same as the sequential version. So, basically, you would get the same results only if using the same seed AND the same numbers of cores. 
Is this the case here?

Comment: you mean because of using seed(), it's normal to have a different result in parallel vs sequential ? I have the same seed in parallel and seq

Comment: I mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46123027/6103040

Comment: I think this link is an another topic. in my program i used the seed at the beginning like : seed(10) . my problem is the different result in parallel program vs sequential program.

Comment: @maryamraz did you solve your problem? I run into a similar issue when comparing the same function using `pblapply` and `lapply`. I also `set.seed()` at the beginning of the script, but I got different results for these two functions.